# Migrate JSONB data to columns

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a PostgreSQL database with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE myrecords (data JSONB);
```

It has some records that look like this:

```
                    data                     
---------------------------------------------
 {"field1": "enabled", "field2": "disabled"}
```

I'd like to migrate the data from a JSON blob to SQL columns; I altered the table like so:

```
ALTER TABLE myrecords ADD COLUMN field1 BOOLEAN;
ALTER TABLE myrecords ADD COLUMN field2 BOOLEAN;
```

I've managed to convert the JSON object to a row using `jsonb_to_record`, but I can't figure out how to (a) convert the "enabled"/"disabled" string literals to BOOLEAN TRUE/FALSE values, and (b) update the row to set the new column values. Is it possible to update a row while at the same time selecting data from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `->>` then compare the result to get a boolean value:

```
update myrecords
  set field1 = (data ->> 'field1') = 'enabled',
      field2 = (data ->> 'field2') = 'enabled'
;
```